# Importing all xlsx files in a folder

Tags: sas

I am using [this](https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Import_all_files_one_type) code to import all xlsx files in a folder:

```
%*Creates a list of all files in the DIR directory with the specified extension (EXT);
%macro list_files(dir,ext);
    %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));
    %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));

    %if &did eq 0 %then
        %do;
            %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;

            %return;
        %end;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));
        %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

        %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then
            %do;
                %put &dir\&name;
                %let file_name =  %qscan(&name,1,.);
                %put &file_name;

                data _tmp;
                    length dir $512 name $100;
                    dir=symget("dir");
                    name=symget("name");
                    path = catx('\',dir,name);
                    the_name = substr(name,1,find(name,'.')-1);
                run;

                proc append base=list data=_tmp force;
                run;

                quit;

                proc sql;
                    drop table _tmp;
                quit;

            %end;
        %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then
            %do;
                %list_files(&dir\&name,&ext)
            %end;
    %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));
%mend list_files;

%*Macro to import a single file, using the path, filename and an output dataset name must be specified;
%macro import_file(path, file_name, dataset_name );

    proc import 
        datafile="&path.\&file_name."
        dbms=xlsx
        out=&dataset_name replace;
    run;

%mend;

*Create the list of files, in this case all XLSX files;
%list_files(c:\_localData\temp, xlsx);

%*Call macro once for each entry in the list table created from the %list_files() macro;
data _null_;
    set list;
    string = catt('%import_file(', dir, ', ',  name,', ', catt('test', put(_n_, z2.)), ');');
    call execute (string);
run;
```

I additionally use the following code to try understand the error being generated: `options mprint mlogic;`

```
MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter PATH has value C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 

      BCH-LJAF\Real data transfer (BCH to UAB)\PreAnalysis\data\DLW cohorts\Cohort 1\1 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter FILE_NAME has value BSL 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter DATASET_NAME has value FB-1208-7 BSL.xlsx 

ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined. 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Ending execution. 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Beginning execution. 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter PATH has value C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 

      BCH-LJAF\Real data transfer (BCH to UAB)\PreAnalysis\data\DLW cohorts\Cohort 1\1 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter FILE_NAME has value BSL 

MLOGIC(IMPORT_FILE):  Parameter DATASET_NAME has value FB-1331-6 BSL.xlsx 

ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.
```

[image]

**Question:** How can I fix this error?

Comment: Glad you found my code useful. It seems like this is an issue with one of your files specifically not all. So I'd try and find which file was generating the issue and check if that name was causing issues and why.

Comment: @Reeza Thank you for creating this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run it successfully using a few test files. This may be an issue with certain characters in your filenames or directories. To prevent this, modify `%import_file` by making the import file a single parameter named `file` that expects a quoted string, then change your `call execute()` string to support it.

```
*Macro to import a single file, using the path, filename and an output dataset name must be specified;
%macro import_file(file, dataset_name);

    proc import 
        datafile=&file.
        dbms=xlsx
        out=&dataset_name replace;
    run;

%mend;

*Create the list of files, in this case all XLSX files;
%list_files(c:\_localData\temp, xlsx);

*Call macro once for each entry in the list table created from the %list_files() macro;
data _null_;
    set list;

    filename = quote(cats(dir, '\', name));
    out      = catt('test', put(_n_, z2.));

    string   = catt('%import_file(', filename, ',', out, ');');

    call execute (string);
run;
```

Comment: Still got this error: ```136  *Create the list of files, in this case all XLSX files;137  %list_files(C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 BCH-LJAF\Real data transfer (BCH to
137! UAB)\PreAnalysis\data\DLW cohorts\Cohort 1\1, BSL, xlsx);
MLOGIC(LIST_FILES):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(LIST_FILES):  Parameter DIR has value C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 BCH-LJAF\Real
      data transfer (BCH to UAB)\PreAnalysis\data\DLW cohorts\Cohort 1\1
MLOGIC(LIST_FILES):  Parameter EXT has value BSL
ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.
MLOGIC(LIST_FILES):  Ending execution.
138```

Comment: Try adding this below the `%local` statement in `%list_files`: `%let dir = %superq(dir); %let ext = %superq(ext);`

Comment: Some subfolders were named like `1, BSL`, `2, PWL`. I manually removed the `1`, and `2`, and test files were generated successfully.

Comment: `,`, `;`, and `*` have been the cause of countless lost hours and dollars across every industry in every programming language :) Glad it's fixed!

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!